# react router v6 loader not called while using useNavigate() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Trying to use the `useNavigate()` hook as defined in `react router v6`, i cannot figure out why loader defined at my route level is not called even if the redirection is done correctly.

It's worth to notice than using a link to access the route is triggering loader correctly.

My route definition :

```
...
{
  path: "differences",
  loader: async () => {
    return loadPractitionersWithDifferences();
  }, //<===== not called
  element: <Differences />,
  children: [
    {
      path: ":id",
      loader: async ({ params }) => {
        return loadDifferenceForPractitioner(params.id);
      },
      element: <Difference />
    }
  ]
};
...
```

The `useNavigate` hook :

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const saveDecisions = () => {
  return axios
    .post("/practitioners/saveDecisions", pra)
    .then(navigate("/differences"));
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't write the `navigate` function in a `then` directly like this. The argument expected by `then` is the function that will be called when the promise is fulfilled. In the code you provided, the navigate is probably triggered immediately when your code is loaded.

You have to pass an anonymous function that will call `navigate`:

```
const saveDecisions = () => {
  return axios
    .post('/practitioners/saveDecisions', pra)
    .then(() => navigate('/differences'));
}
```

Comment: Just tried, but same effect : redirection works ( 'differences' page is rendered), but without any loader called.

Comment: @matthPenDon't you have any errors in the dev console?

Comment: No error, a console log shows me that page is rendered again. Just loader seems not being called

Comment: @Taipan If one you could provide a CodeSandbox reproducting the issue, maybe we could figure out if the problem comes from the code or if it's a bug from React Router.